# Can every irreducible cubic be proved irreducible using the Eisenstein criterion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $f(X,Y) \in k[X,Y]$.  One common way to show that $f$ is irreducible is to regard $f$ an element of $k[X][Y]$ or $k[Y][X]$ and use the Eisenstein criterion.  Since $k$ is algebraically closed, the nonzero prime ideals of $k[X]$ are of the form $(X - x)$ for $x \in k$, and so to apply Eisenstein in this way, $f$ would have to look something like

$$X^3 + g_2(Y-a)X^2 + g_1(Y-a)X + h(Y)(Y-a)$$

for $g_1, g_2 \in Tk[T], h \in k[T], h(Y-a) \neq 0$.

Now, $f$ is irreducible if and only if $f(\phi(X,Y))$ is irreducible, where $\phi$ is an affine transformation of the form $X \mapsto cX + dY + e, Y \mapsto fX + gY + h$, and $\textrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} c& d \\ f &g \end{pmatrix} \neq 0$.  So it is possible that one may prove $f$ is irreducible by applying a change of variables, and then apply the Eisenstein criterion.

My question is, are there examples of irreducible *cubic* polynomials for which **no** change of variables will allow you to conclude irreducibility by the Eisenstein criterion?  If such examples exist, I would particularly be interested in an example with $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p(t)}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at a smooth curve of degree $3$, then no.

This will be an elliptic curve. If $P,Q,R$ are its three points at infinity and $S$ is a point such that $3[S] = [P]+[Q]+[R]$ then the divisor $3[S]-([P]+[Q]+[R])$ is the divisor of the equation of an affine line $ax+by+c = 0$ that goes through a triple point.
Using the coordinates $(x-x_S)$ and $z = ax+by+c$, the equation becomes $(x-x_S)^3 = zg(x-x_S,z)$, and since it's a regular point (I assumed the curve was smooth) you can't have $g(0,0) = 0$ or else both partial derivatives would vanish there.
Then you can apply Eisenstein's criterion there to deduce that the curve is irreducible.

In case $S$ is a point at infinity this may not quite work exactly like this, but since there are $9$ distinct points $S$ and only three points at infinity, you can always find one which is not at infinity.